# Imagemagick crop into tiles and force all to have same size?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to crop an image into 2048x2048 slices like this:

`convert big.jpg -crop 2048x2048 tile%04d.jpg`

However, if the original is for example 5764x3888, the tiles end up like this:

- 2048x2048
- 2048x2048
- 1668x2048
- 2048x1840
- 2048x1840
- 1668x1840

How can I force each tile to be 2048x2048 and sit in the upper left corner?

I would prefer if I could do this in just a command line without a script, since I will do this on both Mac and Windows.

Or do I have to make the original image 6144x4096 first, so it's evenly divisible by 2048 and then crop it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this:

```
convert big.jpg -crop 2048x2048 -background blue -gravity northwest -extent 2048x2048 tile%04d.jpg
```

Obviously choose a different colour background to suit your needs, and choose a different `-gravity` to determine where the cropped image sits on its extended canvas.

Comment: Thanks! I actually was converting transparent PNG images, so I added `-transparent white` to keep the transparency.

Comment: You should be able to use `-background none` and that should be better, else you may unintentionally render white parts of the original image transparent.

Comment: I tried that first, but this made the background white instead of transparent. Not sure if it depends on if the source is 8 or 24-bit png.

Comment: Not sure why that would happen. You can try adding `-alpha on` before `-background none` and you can try forcing all output tiles to have an alpha channel with `convert ... -extent 2048x2048 PNG32:tile%04d.png`

Comment: Thank you, that last command worked. I see the downside to using transparent white, thanks a lot! :)